# Best practices for fetching same data in multiple objects using web service VS front-end computations for accessing existing data?

Tags: android, web-services, frontend

In my application I have fetched some data called **data1** from web server and displayed, after two three screen navigation I need some data which is existing in **data1** but it requires some iterations to access, So is this right I should invoke another web service which is providing required data or front end computations needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can Save your data in a Separate class and fetch from there when you need it,
like getter setter.

Like this..

```
public class Global {
    private  static  JSONObject jsonObject;

    public static void saveData(JSONObject object) {
        jsonObject = object;     
    }
    public static JSONObject getData() {
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

From your Activity:

```
Global.saveData(jsonObject);

Orr

JsonObject jsonObj = Global.getData();
```

Comment: Thanks. But what are the best practices of calling web services?